# What's the best way to highlight C# syntax using Roslyn?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, roslyn

I'm trying to make a Xamarin.Android app that highlights the syntax of many different languages. I plan to use ANTLR to deal with most of them, but for C# I want to use Roslyn as that will undoubtedly be faster and less buggy than ANTLR.

What is the best way to implement syntax highlighting with Roslyn? For highlighting Java syntax, the approach I took was parsing the text into a parse tree, and using a visitor to color the text associated with each terminal. You can view my code [here](https://github.com/jamesqo/Repository/tree/master/Repository.EditorServices/Internal/Languages/Java/SyntaxHighlighting). Is this also a good idea for Roslyn, or does Roslyn provide APIs for syntax highlighting? (e.g. Does the code behind syntax highlighting in Visual Studio live in the [dotnet/roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) repo?) I'd really prefer not to reinvent the wheel, but I will if I have to.

**edit:** I have accepted Tamas' answer because his solution is the most practical for my use case; I do not have access to the full solution to build a semantic model with, so I will have to do some of my own analysis. However, if your app supports more broad C# integration and can build a semantic model, take a look at the Roslyn Classification APIs which are used in Jonathon Marolf's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you have a look at [SourceBrowser](https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/SourceBrowser)? If you can do a full solution build, then I would use the same approach.

If your context doesn't allow a full build, then you can implement something relatively good based on syntax token types. However you might have to handle some corner cases, like contextual keywords, `var`, implicitly declared local variables (like `value`), etc. Have a look at what [SonarQube](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/blob/master/sonaranalyzer-dotnet/src/SonarAnalyzer.Common/Rules/Utilities/TokenTypeAnalyzerBase.cs) is using.

Similarly, you can look for other tools that you know are Roslyn based, like OmniSharp. I'm not sure if that uses regex or Roslyn to do the highlighting. But in any case you could get quite far with Regex too.

Comment: Tamas, thank you for your long and thorough answer. I will try to use Jonathon Marolf's approach first before I try these methods, however, since it looks like Roslyn offers official APIs to do this.

Comment: Perfect. BTW, the ConsoleClassifier uses the same APIs that the SourceBrowser is using (so it needs access to the Workspace).

Comment: Tamas Yeah, I just realized that: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/20261. Unfortunately my app only considers a single `.cs` file at this time, it doesn't offer more broad integration by considering the whole project/solution. I'll accept your answer because I'm looking into SonarQube right now. Thanks for being so helpful!

Answer (score 7):

the [ConsoleClassifier](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-sdk/tree/master/samples/CSharp/ConsoleClassifier) project in the roslyn Samples should be a good starting place.

Comment: Jonathon Marolf, thank you for pointing me to these APIs, I did not know they existed beforehand. This seems almost perfect for my use case. However, is there documentation for what values [`ClassifiedSpan.ClassificationType`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Classification/ClassifiedSpan.cs,ec4d0aa697bfae99,references) can take on?

Comment: Figured it out myself. For anyone who's looking to use these APIs and immediately ran into the exact same question, look at the `ClassificationTypeNames` class.